# Find maximum positive integer value in Bourne Shell

Tags: shell, sh

I'm checking a counter in a loop to determine if it's larger than some maximum, if specified in an optional parameter.  Since it's optional, I can either default the maximum to a special value or to the maximum possible integer. The first option would require an extra check at each iteration, so I'd like to instead find out **what is the maximum integer that will work with the `-gt` Bourne Shell operation**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd stay clear of integer limits as they're non portable and problematic

```
$ test 123412341234112341235 -gt 1 || echo bash compares ints
-bash: test: 123412341234112341235: integer expression expected
bash compares ints
$ env test 1 -gt 123412341234112341235 || echo coreutils compares strings
coreutils compares strings
```

Instead I'd just do as you suggest and do the extra comparison like:

```
[ "$limit" ] && [ $count -gt $limit ]
```

Answer (score 3):

On my system, the maximum integer of Bash seems to be the same as the LONG_MAX constant of my Perl POSIX library. Obviously, this will vary on your platform, and how your Bash was compiled, etc. But that seems to be a good starting point for testing it:

```
declare -i max=$(perl -MPOSIX -le 'print LONG_MAX')

echo $max
9223372036854775807

echo "max+1 = " $(( i += 1 ))
max+1 =  -9223372036854775808

uname -a
Linux x200s 3.2.0-33-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 18 16:29:15 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update: After trying this on an old 32 bit Linux, I see that my Perl's POSIX LONG_MAX is 2147483647, but that Bash still has the same limit. It seems to be defined in /usr/include/limits.h, and to depend on your __WORDSIZE, which may be 64 bits even on 32 bit systems :

```
/* Minimum and maximum values a `signed long int' can hold.  */
#  if __WORDSIZE == 64
#   define LONG_MAX     9223372036854775807L
#  else
#   define LONG_MAX     2147483647L
#  endif
```

Comment: on macOSX Catalina |
`Mac:~ Erik$ uname -a` |
`Darwin Mac.local 19.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64` |
`Mac:~ Erik$ a=9223372036854775807; echo "a+1 = $(($a+1)) ; a/(1024x1024x1024) = $(($a/1073741824)) ;"; unset a;` |
`a+1 = -9223372036854775808 ; a/(1024x1024x1024) = 8589934591 ;` |
`Mac:~ Erik$ bash --version` |
`GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)` |
`Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` |
`Mac:~ Erik$ zsh --version` |
`zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)`

Answer (score 1):

The Bourne shell has no facilities for storing or manipulating numbers - everything is stored as a string. If you are asking about this kind of thing:

```
if [ $x -gt $y ]
```

then that is handled by a separate (in the Bourne shell) executable called `test`, which has a symbolic link called '['.  So your question is really about the limits of the `test` command, which all the docs I can find seem quite reticent about.