# shell bit shifting producing different numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, embedded

in my local machines bash when I run:

```
echo $((192 << 24))
3221225472
```

but on my embedded targets busy box SHELL I get something else:

```
echo $((192 << 24))
-1073741824
```

it works when I left shift by a smaller number though. The embedded device is 64bit, where my local host is 32 bit.

Just to be clear, **on the 32bit machine, the value is positive, on the 64 bit machine it's negative.**

EDIT:
This is on the embedded device which is **64 bit machine with SHELL**. It doesn't happen when left shifting by 23.

```
echo $((192 << 23))
1610612736
echo $((192 << 24))
-1073741824
```

On the local host, which is a **32 machine with BASH**:

```
echo $((192 << 55))
6917529027641081856
echo $((192 << 56))
-4611686018427387904
```

Comment: Curious, what's the version of busybox you're using?

Comment: The image is using busybox `1.13.2` where the latest one from the website is `1.21.1`

Comment: FWIW, you might be running into [this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=635370) issue.

Comment: very likely. You are not a null my friend, dev on.

Comment: Upgrade, upgrade!  And rejoice!

Comment: That word scares some folks in my department.

Comment: @devnull - no, it is only very distantly related to that - both concern unwanted sign-bit interpretation, but in completely different situations.

Comment: @Chris: So it's not a bug?

Comment: @ArmenB. - most likely, it is only a "bug" in the sense that you are expecting different behavior than the system was designed to provide.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I meant whether if it is a bug in BusyBox.

Comment: @ArmenB. - no, it is not a bug in busybox.  It is a bug, or at least risky expectation, in the shell script which performs this calculation as the calculation will give different results across different shell implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX ([here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04)) says "Only signed long integer arithmetic is required", and in C a long is at least 32 bits; that being said, some shells explicitly choose a fixed width, eg mksh uses 32 bits arithmetic, and peeking at the busybox' source (math.h) it seems like they only use 64 bits is ENABLE_SH_MATH_SUPPORT_64 is #define'd, regardless of whether the underlying system is 32/64 bits.
If anyone knows better, speak up!

Comment: Nice answer. If busybox is using 64 bit, then why the integer overflow? What version of busy boxes source code where you looking at?

Comment: I was looking at the version included with debian, but I just checked their latest snapshot and it does the same

Comment: A quick look at bash (specifically expr.c) indicates they use intmax_t, which is guaranteed to be >= 64 bits even on 32 bits platform; about the overflow, I think the machine where you're running   busybox has 32 bits long integers -- IL32P64, can you check?

Answer (score 3):

The binary representation of `192` is `11000000`. When you shift it left 24 places, the only two bits which are set are the two most significant bits - the representation is `11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`. When a 32 bit system sees the most significant bit set, it interprets it as a negative number in "two's complement" format. For a 64 bit system, the most significant bit is still zero, so it is interpreted as a positive number.

This is simply an integer overflow on the 32 bit machine. You could expect the same behavior in C or any other language when using 32 vs 64 bit signed integer types.

Comment: on the 32 bit machine the result is 3221225472, on the 64 bit it's -1073741824.

Comment: OK, but regardless the one that returns the negative number is using a signed 32 bit integer type. So therefore the embedded shell is using either unsigned 32 bit or bignum integers and the shell on the 64 bit machine still uses 32 bit signed integers by default.

Comment: Yes, you could be right, with these numbers it could be a signed vs. unsigned thing

Answer (score 1):

It's apparent that the result is overflowing on your embedded device.  Some calculations based on your findings seem to substantiate the *hypothesis*:

```
$ echo 3221225472 - 1073741824 | bc -l
2147483648

$ echo 2^31 | bc -l
2147483648
```

If you try with more on your local machine, you'd figure that it'd overflow too!

```
$ echo $((192 << 56))
-4611686018427387904
```

EDIT: As you've [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898715/shell-bit-shifting-producing-different-numbers#comment27897176_18898715) that you're Busybox 1.13.2, there's a chance that you're running into [this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=635370) issue.  Upgrading might help!

Comment: This is not a bug in the shell, it is expected behavior as the shell uses a signed type, and this would overflow the platform's signed long.  See for a comparative example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965761/find-maximum-positive-integer-value-in-bourne-shell

Comment: @ChrisStratton Overflow was the first thing that was told to the OP

Comment: you are pointing to an actual bug which has nothing to do with the poster's problem.  The poster's problem is not a bug in busybox, but rather expected behavior of a shell which uses a 32 bit signed integer, as many have traditionally done.

Answer (score 1):

Well it simply because of the number of bits the number is represented. 192 (0xc0) when shifted becomes 0xc0000000. On a 32 bit machine, it's already a negative number whereas on a 64bit machine, it's still on the range of a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost answered your own question - the shell in the 32bit machine presumably uses 32bit signed integers for this kind of arithmetic, whereas the shell in the 64bit machine presumably uses 64bit signed integers. With 32bit signed integers, the max possible value is 2^31, so 3221225472 would result in an overflow.

Comment: on the 32 bit machine no overflow is occurring. The value is 3221225472.

Comment: Ok, so in this case the 32bit vs 64bit machine difference is a red herring.  The 32bit machine's shell must be using unsigned integers, whereas the 64bit machine's shell must be using signed integers.  What versions of bash are being used?  `bash --version`

Comment: @ArmenB. - it's not really the word size of the processor that is at issue, it's word size of whatever variable a given shell is using.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same on on my native embedded android shell but after starting busybox shell it works correctly.

```
# echo $((192 << 23))
1610612736
# echo $((192 << 23))
1610612736
# echo $((192 << 24))
-1073741824

# busybox sh
/ # echo $((192 << 23))
1610612736
/ # echo $((192 << 24))
3221225472
/ # busybox
```

using BusyBox v1.19.3