# Why bash return negetive number instead of 2^64?

Tags: linux, bash

I write a simple bash script to calculate 2^63 but it return -9223372036854775808 as result! It can calculate 2^60 correctly. Can anybody explain why this happen?

Comment: If you want to ask about a problem with a script, it helps to *actually include the script* (or, rather, a [mcve] demonstrating the problem) *in your question*. There's more than one way to do this math, and some of them (ie. `bc`) actually work.

Comment: More suitable for superuser, see https://superuser.com/questions/1030122/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-a-numeric-bash-shell-variable

Comment: Basically, that is exactly, what the overflow term means.
Each system has some "maximal" value, if that one is increased, you got the "next one" from the interval start. 
Eg. If your imaginary allowed interval will be from 4 to 10, and you will increase "1" into 10, you got number 4.
From the other side, it is called underflow- if you will have 4 and decrase "1", you got number 10..

Usually there is also some "under/over flow flag", which indicates this fact. 
Its like in decimal number- single char is max 9, if you increase "1" you also got 10- two char value

Comment: Also see [Find maximum positive integer value in Bourne Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2965761/608639) and [What is the maximum value of a numeric bash shell variable?](https://superuser.com/q/1030122/173513)

Comment: Simply easy you can imagine it on the car analog distance counter like on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow :) // odometer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash on your system uses 64 bit signed ints, so the largest positive value is 2^63-1.

2^63 wraps around to negative and represents the smallest (largest negative value) of -2^63.

Note the that on other systems Bash might not use 64 bit integers, `man bash` only states "Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow".

Comment: Rather, the OP's particularly platform uses 64-bit signed ints; `bash` itself makes no promises about how much precision is available.

Comment: @chepner Updated the answer